# Apache redirect to parent location

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 2 requirements as follow,
1 All example.com/eu/en/* redirects to example.com/de/de/* (1:1 redirect)
2 If the above page does not finds a redirect page then it need to redirect to its parent page like below,

example.com/eu/en/about/news/1024.html is not found in de/de

then the page need to redirect to
example.com/de/de/about.html

For #1 i have a rule setup like below

```
 RewriteRule ^/eu/de/about/(.*)$   www.example.com/de/de/about/$1   [R=301,L]
```

But for #2 i have no idea....

your suggestions are highly appreciated!!!